# What was the real purpose of Shukla Yajurveda?

Tags: vedas, vedanta, yajur-veda, vedic-rituals

What was the purpose of Shukla Yajurveda when the Krishna Yajurveda was already present?
Inviting answer from Any Vedic scholar on any references to the purpose. Sun instructed that to Ygnyavalkya.